# Man whose job is to destroy broken robots on Mars

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, robots

Could anyone help me please. I am looking for a short story where the setting is on Mars, protagonist a human waste disposal worker. His job is to shovel broken down robots into the furnace and they make disturbing sounds as they get shoveled in.

I think the title was something like "They told a story"

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe [Strikebreaker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strikebreaker_(short_story)) by Asimov? A visitor learns that the resident garbage disposal worker is on strike, and there's a strong social taboo on anyone else doing that job, so the visitor volunteers for the job, but now he's turned himself into a pariah.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.